# iPhone App Crashing loading view

Tags: ios, ios5

So I was looking at ways to change my view.

I have this line in the ViewController.m

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Hotel" imageName:@"ks"
    viewController:ks removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Restaurant" imageName:@"nh" viewController:nh removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Winery" imageName:@"qa" viewController:qa removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Dating" imageName:@"bar" viewController:bar removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Shopping" imageName:@"ba" viewController:ba removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Art" imageName:@"ck" viewController:ck removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Games" imageName:@"kar" viewController:kar removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Phamarcy" imageName:@"th" viewController:th removable:NO]];
[items addObject:[SEMenuItem initWithTitle:@"Gas station" imageName:@"tx" viewController:tx removable:NO]];
SESpringBoard *board = [SESpringBoard initWithTitle:@"Welcome" items:items launcherImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbtn_home.png"]];
[primaryView addSubview:board];
[self.view addSubview:primaryView];
```

}

all I did was change the `viewController:ks` to something else and change it back. Now I just get the error that there's a thread break point.  I tried restoring from a backup, but it still gives me the same error.

I don't understand why.  Do I have to link to something physical in the view?

BTW the app builds just fine... loads the first view then crashes before the view where this would load

EDIT: It just says "Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: please post the error, without that information nobody can help you.

Comment: I adwise you to use a Version Control System (VCS) like git to track your changes. So you can always see what you changed.

Comment: Need to see error/more code, Presume 'items' is an NSArray. Do you have a local or instance variable name ks that references a UIViewController instance?

Comment: Remove the breakpoint

Comment: According to your error message - you just have a breakpoint set on that line - search for blue thing to the left of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck the breakpoint to the left of the code. Click in the red circled area to remove the blue arrow.

For more information see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hahahahahahhahaha. Thank you so much. I was having a HEART ATTACK!

Comment: No problem at all! If you are happy please mark as correct answer :)